# Page break for media print for Zurb Foundation 5

Tags: css, printing, zurb-foundation

I want to print some pages from my site using Foundation 5 ccs framework. In my css I add this lines:

```
@media print {
   hr.page-break{page-break-after:always!important;}      
}
```

I use .page break class to simply add new page for printing, but didn't work.
When remove all foundation 5 styles, the new pages printed as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

These are the only print styles for F5 (from `/foundation/components/_type.scss`) so I'm not seeing anything that would relate to `hr` in there.

```
  @media print {
    * {
      background: transparent !important;
      color: #000 !important; /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
      box-shadow: none !important;
      text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    a,
    a:visited { text-decoration: underline;}
    a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; }

    abbr[title]:after { content: " (" attr(title) ")"; }

    // Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links
    .ir a:after,
    a[href^="javascript:"]:after,
    a[href^="#"]:after { content: ""; }

    pre,
    blockquote {
      border: 1px solid #999;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    thead { display: table-header-group; /* h5bp.com/t */ }

    tr,
    img { page-break-inside: avoid; }

    img { max-width: 100% !important; }

    @page { margin: 0.5cm; }

    p,
    h2,
    h3 {
      orphans: 3;
      widows: 3;
    }

    h2,
    h3 { page-break-after: avoid; }

    .hide-on-print { display: none !important; }
    .print-only { display: block !important; }
    .hide-for-print { display: none !important; }
    .show-for-print { display: inherit !important; }
  }
```

Also - don't believe that this should matter, but I've never seen a select with `!important` attached to a value without a space in-between, so I'd put a space there.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that:

```
.columns {
  float:left;
}
```

more or less nullifies `page-break-*` attributes. If you're elements have a parent with the class `.columns` this is probably the issue.

A simple way to deal with this is to remove the float at the upper level element, with something like:

```
@media print {
  div.columns {
    float:none;
  }
}
```

I stumbled across this thread because I was looking for a more selective method to do the same thing. This overall change may mess up how your page looks.